# How to store the pre chat form details in the chat transcript

Tags: community, salesforcedx, liveagent

I just need some help in live agent chat, I have to store the pre-chat form records in the chat transcript object. For now, the record is creating in the contact object but fetch the record details in chat transcript through trigger and process builder is not working

Can anyone have an idea about how can we store the data in the chat transcript?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
<input type="hidden" name= "liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript: String entityName" value= "String transcriptFieldName" />
```

This method allows you to save the field to the transcript object. [Documentation Link.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_creating_records_prechat_API_saveToTranscript.htm)

Sample:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Case" value="CaseId" />
```